# search the queue sizes in a vector

Tags: c++, loops, vector, queue

I have a paradigm where a integer before gets enqueued to a queue in a vector, the loop of queues is searched and integer is enqueued to a queue which has minimum size among the queues. the following code shows the operation.

```
#include <vector> 
#include <queue> 
std::vector<std::queue<int> > q
int min_index = 0;
std::size_t size = q.size();
for( i=0; i<size; i++){ //accessing loop of queues
    if(q[min_index].size() > q[i].size())
        min_index = i; // Now q[min_index] is the shortest queue
} 
q[min_index].push(int)
```

next i am trying to extend my paradigm with the condition, that the integers should be enqueued to the shortest queue until it becomes maximum size among the queues.

```
do{
   q[min_index].push(int)
} while(q[min_index].size > queue sizes in the vector loop except this queue )
```

how to search the loop of queue sizes except this queue
any ideas please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply calculate the max queue size as well as the minimum index:

```
int min_index = 0;
int max_size = -1;
std::size_t size = q.size();
for( i=0; i<size; i++){ //accessing loop of queues
    if(q[min_index].size() > q[i].size())
        min_index = i; // Now q[min_index] is the shortest queue
    if(q[i].size() > max_size)
        max_size = q[i].size(); // longest queue
} 
while(q[min_index].size < max_size)
{
    q[min_index].push(int);
}
```

Comment: @eladidanSo here the q[min_index] queue will be pushing the integers until it becomes the maximimum among the queues right?

Comment: exactly, but with one distinction. It will be A maximum queue, not THE maximum queue. Meaning, it will grow in size until it is AS big as a max sized queue but then it will stop pushing. If you want it to be THE ONLY max sized queue you will need to push one more int to the queue (change the condition on the while to <= instead of <)

Comment: @eladidanSo for while<= it will become THE maximum queue and exits the loop (stops pushing), right?

Comment: sorry eladidan, i cant upvote as my reputation is less than 15, will surely upvote when i get 15rep

Comment: @billa: yes, exactly. And regarding the upvote you're right, I should've remembered that:)

Comment: @eladidanIf i need the calculate all the sizes of queues in the loop, and push the integers until the shortest queue count is less than or equal to any other count in the queue, how can i do? i can use std::size(q.begin(),q.end(), []) and get all the sizes?

Comment: @billa: "i need [to]... push the integers until the shortest queue count is less than or equal to any other count in the queue". What do you mean? The shortest queue's size IS by definition  less than or equal to any other queue size. Anyway, the comment section is intended to note on the given answer and not for a new question. If you have a new question, conduct a search to see if it's been asked before and if not, ask a new question.